# App Crash - iOS EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)

Tags: ios, crash

I've been working on an app for quite a while and everything works fine but occasionally it will just randomly crash and I have no idea why/where as the report only points to main.m. Any ideas?

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x2333b0d2 __exceptionPreprocess + 122
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x31a7ac72 objc_exception_throw + 34
2   CoreFoundation                  0x2333ab58 __NSFastEnumerationMutationHandler + 124
3   UIKit                           0x26994a7a -[UIView(Hierarchy) subviews] + 298
4   UIKit                           0x26fcd94e -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _internalUpdateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPassAndViewsNeedingBaselineUpdate:] + 78
5   Foundation                      0x23ff3414 -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:] + 252
6   UIKit                           0x26fcdbce -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPassAndViewsNeedingBaselineUpdate:] + 118
7   UIKit                           0x26a894cc __60-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) updateConstraintsIfNeeded]_block_invoke + 80
8   Foundation                      0x23ff3414 -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:] + 252
9   UIKit                           0x26a892a4 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) updateConstraintsIfNeeded] + 200
10  UIKit                           0x26fcde64 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _updateConstraintsAtEngineLevelIfNeeded] + 168
11  UIKit                           0x26c3daea -[UIView(Hierarchy) _updateConstraintsAsNecessaryAndApplyLayoutFromEngine] + 114
12  UIKit                           0x269999c6 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 542
13  QuartzCore                      0x263af3e0 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 124
14  QuartzCore                      0x263aac30 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 356
15  QuartzCore                      0x263aaab8 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 12
16  QuartzCore                      0x263aa45a CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 218
17  QuartzCore                      0x263aa24a CA::Transaction::commit() + 430
18  QuartzCore                      0x263a3f58 CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 52
19  CoreFoundation                  0x23301048 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 16
20  CoreFoundation                  0x232fe72c __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 272
21  CoreFoundation                  0x232feb2e __CFRunLoopRun + 910
22  CoreFoundation                  0x2324a6cc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 472
23  CoreFoundation                  0x2324a4de CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
24  GraphicsServices                0x2abe61a4 GSEventRunModal + 132
25  UIKit                           0x269fc440 UIApplicationMain + 1436
26  **My App**                      0x0015a91c main (main.m:14)
27  libdyld.dylib                   0x32048aaa tlv_initializer + 2
```

Comment: Looks like the view hierarchy is being changed during an auto-layout update. Do you have any pattern of what's happening when you get the crash?

Comment: I think that we need you to show off some code to help you

Comment: There are lots of files working together so I have no idea what one is causing it, auto layout isn't used and every object is moved on the screen by formulas (there are 100's of views on the screen at once so narrowing it down is quite difficult). When it crashes nothing odd happens in the UI and it's more random than happening with a set of actions (ie I can't duplicate it).